# How to show token.text "[wants,pizza]" according arrow in SPACY Dependency Parser with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy-3

Other case I have try successfully, based on SPACY dependency parser, word 'pizza' is "dobj" and link to word 'cola' as 'conj'. But, I don't know how to show text '[wants,pizza]' ?

```
import deplacy
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text='John said "He wants a pizza and cola"'
doc = nlp(text)

deplacy.render(doc)

for token in doc:
    if token.dep_=='dobj':
        dobj=[token.text]
        conj=[t.text for t in token.conjuncts]
    dobj_conj=dobj+conj
print(dobj_conj)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for token in doc:
    if token.dep_=='dobj':
        dobj=[token.text]
        conj=[token.head.text]
    dobj_conj=dobj+conj
print(dobj_conj)
```